# What are the pros and cons of using a slider for blogs?

Tags: usability, content, sliders, blog

An example can be found on this [link](https://site.uplabs.com/posts/blog-post-transitions)

What are the pros and cons of using a slider to view recent posts of a blog? Is it better than simply using article cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Should I Use a Carousel](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/) website was built specifically to answer this question.